# Renewing members being flagged as new

Tags: wordpress, civimember

Here are our membership rules, they seem ok.
[image: Member rules]We're using CiviCRM 5.58.1 with Wordpress. After a recent set of upgrades we are experiencing an issue where current members who are renewing their membership are now flagged as new members after renewing. My guess is that this is as a result of Civi being unable to match the fields correctly. Is anyone else having this issue and do you have any suggestions as to how to resolve the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you say they're "flagged as new", I assume you mean their Membership Status field is marked "New".

If so, then someone has probably configured the membership statuses incorrectly.  Go to **Administer menu » CiviMember » Membership Status Rules**.  My guess is someone has modified the *New* status to use *Start Date* and not *Join Date*.

Below is a screenshot of the statuses as they appear on a new installation of CiviCRM.
[image: Default CiviCRM membership statuses]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've uploaded the rules above and they don't seem much different to the ones you've added. Can you think of anything else?

Comment: Can you check if the 'Update Membership Statuses' scheduled job is running?
Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs

Comment: @Alg I second Anil's suggestion.  It may well be that you've fixed the problem, but that won't change existing statuses, you need to run the scheduled job.

Comment: @Anil The Membership status processor job seems to be running fine. I executed as per your advice but then checked and it ran and updated records yesterday so not sure what's going on here...

Comment: @alg Try clicking "Edit" on a membership that has the wrong status, then click "Save" without changing anything. Memberships automatically recalculate status on save.  If you're still having trouble, you may want to post a screenshot of the troublesome membership.

Comment: Thanks again for your help - I've clarified with the people that use it and we have a "New" form and an "Renew" membership form. To become a new member, they use the new form which has personal details as well as their email. On the renew form, it only has their email, the renew form used to match correctly existing membership. What has happened is that it isn't a status issue at all. It's actually creating a new record because it's not matching by email, so you end up having to merge the existing record and the record from the renew form.